# time_zone select in Rails without region

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

I am trying to use the `time_zone_select` helper with Rails which outputs the select

```
    <%= f.time_zone_select(:time_zone) %>
```

HTML output is:

```
<option value="Belgrade">(GMT+01:00) Belgrade</option>
```

All my timezones I have been calculated using a separate `rake` task that has stored the time zone as a string in my database in the format of:

**Europe/Belgrade**

This causes issues with editing the record as the `time_zone_select` doesn't store the values with the region. What am I doing wrong or what can I do to get around this?

---

**More info******

This rake task I have created creates and stores time zones using [ActiveSupport::TimeZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html).

When I create a time zone object, the **name** attribute returns a string **"Europe/Belgrade"** but the time zone helper expects this value to be **"Belgrade"**